# Permission Denied Opening ligEGL shader cache file

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, eclipse-cdt, cocos2d-x-3.0

As I mention in the title, my app built successful but show a blank screen and quit after a few second when I run it on device (SS GLX Tab3 Intel). And the logcat showed
 `error opening cache file /data/data/com.abc.testapp/cache/com.android.opengl.shaders_cache: Permission denied (13)` with `libEGL` tag.

Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Any helps would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I got the same question. any one know how to solve it ?

Comment: Me also same problem.

Comment: I got this error, too. I was searching about this error and found some stuffs, maybe this error is occurring by the elevation (shadow) drawn by Android on some devices. I think, that's the reason, but I'm not sure. Please test and post the result.

Comment: did anyone get the answer?

Comment: Did anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it works by adding this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
```

You do not have the permission to open the cache file. You can also try to give your app manualy the permission to read files: APP info>Permissions>Storage

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?